# Transfer files between git branches in local

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have accidentally worked on `master` instead of an issue-branch, I have managed to make edits in multiple files in the repo.
I haven't committed/pushed the changes yet. can someone suggest me how to transfer this local changes to other branch so that I can create the pull request to master.

I am new to git, really sorry if this is a noob question.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't committed yet, you could:

```
# check the current branch (should be master) 
git branch 

# create a new branch starting from master which will contain your modifications
git checkout -b new_branch
```

Or

```
git stash
git checkout <other_branch>
git stash pop
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

1. Just checkout the other branch. Git will complain if this is impossible (usually due to files you modified being different on the branch you want to checkout).
2. `git stash`, checkout the other branch, and `git stash pop`. This avoids the previous error, and the stash pop will give you a chance to resolve any merge conflicts.
3. Commit your changes (yes, on your local master branch), checkout the other branch, cherry-pick the commit (resolve any conflicts) and then you can checkout and reset master to right before your commits. This has the advantage of tracking everything with commits (although the stash also is tracked), gives you full control of all the steps, but requires you to reset the master branch once you've cherry-picked your commit(s).